# Char Input of Multiple Chars With Spaces in Between

Tags: java, input, char, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a grade class which determines one's chances of getting into college. The user should input something like: A B C D F E. The program should stop at E, as it is not a grade. The program also calculates GPA. In the Driver(included below), I call the print and the set functions, however, it simply does not exit the set loop.

Main Grades Class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Grades {
//Declare instance variables here
private int numClass;
private double gpa;
public int count = 0;
public boolean gotF = false;
/**
 * Method to get the grades and calculate the GPA
 * This method also counts the number of classes taken
 * and the number of Fs
 */
public void getGradesAndCalculateGPA()
{
    //Your code goes here

    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a set of grades:");
    do {
        count += 1;
        if(stdin.next().charAt(0) == 'A') {
            gpa += 4.0;
            //System.out.println("Grade Inputted");
        }
        else if(stdin.next().charAt(0) == 'B') {
            gpa += 3.0;
            //System.out.println("Grade Inputted");
        }
        else if(stdin.next().charAt(0) == 'C') {
            gpa += 2.0;
            //System.out.println("Grade Inputted");
        }
        else if(stdin.next().charAt(0) == 'D') {
            gpa += 1.0;
            //System.out.println("Grade Inputted");
        }
        else if(stdin.next().charAt(0) == 'F') {
            gpa += 0.0;
            gotF = true;
            //System.out.println("Grade Inputted");
        }
    }while(stdin.next().charAt(0) == 'A' ||
            stdin.next().charAt(0) == 'B' ||
            stdin.next().charAt(0) == 'C' ||
            stdin.next().charAt(0) == 'D' ||
            stdin.next().charAt(0) == 'F');
    gpa = gpa/count;


}
/**
 * Method to print the appropriate message
 */
public void printMessage()
{
    //Your code goes here
    if(count < 4) {
        System.out.printf("%7s %12d %30s", "", gpa, "Ineligible, taking less than four classes");
    }
    else if(gotF==true && gpa<2.0) {
        System.out.printf("%7s %12d %30s", "", gpa, "Ineligible, gpa below 2.0 and has F grade");
    }
    else if(gotF == true) {
        System.out.printf("%7s %12d %30s", "", gpa, "Ineligible, gpa above 2.0 but has F grade");
    }
    else if(gpa < 2.0) {
        System.out.printf("%7s %12d %30s", "", gpa, "Ineligible, gpa below 2.0");
    }
    else {
        System.out.printf("%7s %12d %8s", "", gpa, "Eligible");
    }

}

}
```

Here is the driver class:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Grades grader = new Grades();
        grader.getGradesAndCalculateGPA();
        grader.printMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to know how to stop taking input from user once he enters non valid grade ?

Comment: note that stdin.next() consumes a token, calling it twice will consume two tokens, then it's quite probably that the effect is not what you want, that means that your first if will evaluate the 'A', and if it fails, the second if will evaluate the 'B' for the input "A B".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call `stdin.next()`, the `Scanner` waits until the user types something and hits enter. Your code is stacking up those statements with each if statement and is disrupting the programmatic flow. I fixed your code to only ask for the user input once per grade and store it in the `grade` variable for use in the if statements. I also added the `validGrade` boolean to break the loop when an invalid grade is entered.

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a set of grades:");
boolean validGrade = true;

while (validGrade) {
    count += 1;
    char grade = stdin.next().charAt(0);
    if (grade == 'A') {
        gpa += 4.0;
        System.out.println("Grade Inputted");
    } else if (grade == 'B') {
        gpa += 3.0;
        System.out.println("Grade Inputted");
    } else if (grade == 'C') {
        gpa += 2.0;
        System.out.println("Grade Inputted");
    } else if (grade == 'D') {
        gpa += 1.0;
        System.out.println("Grade Inputted");
    } else if (grade == 'F') {
        gotF = true;
        System.out.println("Grade Inputted");
    } else {
        validGrade = false;
    }
}

gpa = gpa / count;
System.out.println("Your GPA is: " + gpa);
```

Comment: This works when I input: A B C D E, but does not work when I enter in A B C D

Comment: @DhruvJain yes, that’s what you asked for in the question